# Using Remote API in Pycharm Google App Engine Project

Tags: python, eclipse, google-app-engine, pycharm

I have recently moved over to PyCharm from Eclipse due to reading a lot of recommendations about how good PyCharm is, but I am now having a problem.  Before, on Eclipse, I ran the development server, then I executed my remote access script, which was embedded within the project, e.g.

```
src
 - templates
 - model
 - some python
 - remote_api
   - access_development.py
 - app.yaml
 - etc.
```

When I ran `access_development.py`, under eclipse, I could access all of the python classes for example under model. Now in PyCharm, it cannot access it when I run it as a standard python run.

Anyone have any ideas how to

A) have access_development.py gain access to the model, and
B) run it as an independent script so that I can populate the google app engine database on my local server.

I need A as well for my production server.

Answer (score 0):

So, after much digging, on PyCharm vs Eclipse, eclipse automatically designate sources in a project, while PyCharm requires you to select the appropriate folders as source folders vs template folders.  You get to this in `File --> Settings --> Project Structure`.  Once you denote all of the folders necessary as Source, it works perfectly.  Hope this helps others since I have been beating my head against a wall for a while.